# How do I store editor-configurable snippets of configuration?

Tags: nodes, configuration, 8

The Drupal 8 site I'm building contains some custom forms and pages. On those pages, bits information are inserted that must remain editable by the site editors. In D7, I would probably have used the Variables module for this. There are a couple of options, but none of these seems the ideal solution.

Possible solutions:

- **Use the [State API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api).**
  Pro: Does not revert on a config-import.
  Con: Not really meant for this kind of data.
- **Use the [Config API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api).**
  Pro: Easy to deploy initial values.
  Con: Needs something like [Config Ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore) to protect the data from being reverted on a config-import.
- **Create a node type for this kind of information.**
  Pro: Provides a well-known admin UI be default.
  Con: Lots of overhead for storing a simple value. No native machine name to reference the value.

Question:
How should I store snippets of editor-configurable information, so that it can be retrieved by a machine name, and will not be reverted when a developer does a config import?

Comment: Sounds like configuration to me, as you mentioned, there are various ways to exclude certain configuration from being overwritten, https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split might be worth looking into. Usually, my workflow simply involves exporting from prod, then merging the new config in, then deploy and import that.